# PHP: Как узнать из какого файла вызвана функция

Tags: php, битрикс

Задача такова:
В шаблоне сайта на 1С Битрикс "Управление сайтом" вызвана php-функция.

$arTest = getTestFromApi();

Как узнать из какого файла вызвана функция?

Answer (score 2):

Функция debug_print_backtrace() https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.debug-print-backtrace.php вполне подходит для этого. Либо используйте отладку вашей IDE.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. А можете еще подсказать, как правильно воспользоваться данной функцией, для решения описанной задачи?